# Add CAN interface in Azure IoT Edge

Tags: azure-iot-edge

I am using Azure IoT Edge to implement a IoT solution on Ubuntu 20.04. the edge computer setup CAN interface that is working using following command:

```
ip link set can0 type can bitrate 500000
```

This command works in Linux computer. Azure IoT Edge is a docker container, when I execute this command inside the container, it returns:

```
Cannot find device "can0"
```

When I type the following command in the container:

```
ip link ls
```

It does not have can0.

Does anyone know how to bind the CAN interface to docker?

I found that Azure IoT Edge is using Moby Engine, it seems have different behavior than docker. Since I have added

```
         "createOptions": {
            "NetworkingConfig": { "EndpointsConfig": { "host": {} } },
            "HostConfig": {
              "NetworkMode": "host",
              "CapAdd": [ "NET_ADMIN" ],
              "CapDrop": [ "CHOWN", "SETUID" ]
            }
          }
```

to the deployment.template.json. But the can0 does not exist.

**Extra Information:**
In the host, use command **ip link ls**, it returns

```
4: can0: <NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP,ECHO> mtu 16 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 10
link/can
```

using command **ifconfig**, it returns

```
can0: flags=193<UP,RUNNING,NOARP>  mtu 16
    unspec 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00-00  txqueuelen 10  (UNSPEC)
    RX packets 1244494  bytes 9396052 (9.3 MB)
    RX errors 2  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 2
    TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

But in Azure IoT Edge, it has eth0 and lo only.

Comment: You can run the container in the host network namespace (`docker run --net=host`), which will give it access to all your host interfaces.

Comment: Have you tried with `--device`? I haven't tried it myself, but it seems promising. https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-host-device-to-container---device

Comment: @larsks I tried but fail. It has eth0 but not can0

Comment: @frippe the can0 or can does not show in /dev. can0 only show in "ip link ls"

Comment: @larsks I tried to use `docker run --net=host` and it works. But not work when using the setting in deployment.template.json of the Azure IoT Edge project